# Rails and state_machine gem, when before_transition fails, transition to an error state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I am using the state_machine gem to track the status of an object.  I have a before_transition process to run and if that has any errors, I would like to set the object's state to "errored" so it is no longer an active object and I am notified that something went wrong.  Below is a simplified code snippet to demonstrate what I am trying to do:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine :initial => :pending do
    state :pending
    state :processed
    state :errored

    event :process do
      transition :pending => :processed
    end
    event :error do
      transition all => :errored
    end

    before_transition :on => :process, :do => :processing_task
    after_failure :on => :process, :do => :log_error
  end

  def processing_task
    puts "Processing Task Started"
    ...do some processing...
    false  #to force the before_transition task to fail
  end

  def log_error
    puts "Error detected, logging results"
    #LogUtility to store error
    error
  end
end
```

When I run `status.process` I receive the following:

```
BEGIN
Processing Task Started
Error detected, logging results
UPDATE SQL COMMAND, state = 'errored'
ROLLBACK
```

I tried to disable transactions `state_machine :initial => :pending, :use_transactions => false'` but that didn't make a difference.  I feel like I should be able to transition an `errored` state when detecting an error during a before_transition process??

**UPDATE**

I tried to do something like this:

```
def custom_process
  begin
    process!
  rescue => e
    puts e      #debugging purposes
    #log error
    error       #transition to error state
  end
end
```

Then i can call `object.custom_process` and this accomplishes my goal but I'm creating my own transition outside the state machine, which feels a little weird to me.  If this is the only way, I can implement it like this but was hoping to keep everything inside the state machine.

Comment: Looks like you can't transition to a state if there is any error. Since your `error` is called during the process of transition, it will get rolled back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was able to create a custom method to achieve my desired outcome and posted it as an update on the original message.  But it doesn't feel right to me that this process isn't defined within the state machine.

Comment: You can try to use an ActiveJob to schedule the change of state to error state in about 1 minute or so.